# How to launch second Phonegap activity in the same project?

Tags: android, cordova

In my phonegap project, I have two activity, Mainactivity and Secondactivity, I write a plugin for Mainactivity to lauch Secondactivity by using Intent. By I always faild and got some error log :

```
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1683)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub.access$7900(WebViewCore.java:926)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.removeMessages(WebViewCore.java:1795)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at android.webkit.WebView.sendOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:2917)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at android.webkit.ZoomManager.setZoomScale(ZoomManager.java:593)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at android.webkit.ZoomManager.access$1700(ZoomManager.java:49)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at android.webkit.ZoomManager$PostScale.run(ZoomManager.java:984)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-28 12:11:07.298: W/webcore(924):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 12:12:06.738: E/CordovaWebView(924): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
```

and got:

```
CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful. URL=file:///android_asset/www//Second.html
```

if I use codorva 1.8.1 I got:

```
08-28 15:13:03.020: W/webcore(29758): java.lang.Throwable: EventHub.removeMessages(int what = 107) is not supported before the WebViewCore is set up.
08-28 15:13:22.850: W/webview(29758): java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread 'Thread-7765'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.
```

Here is my SecondActivity code:

```
public class Secondactivity extends DroidGap {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000); 
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www//Second.html");
    }
}
```

My Mainactivity also extends DroidGap.

Can anyone give me some hint?

=============================================
I replaceed startActivity with startActivityForResult, that worked!

Comment: What are you doing that requires two different activities?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line .

```
 super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/Second.html");
```

there is error here `//Second.html`

Comment: @user1630239 Remove super.init();

Comment: I remove "super.init()", but still not work.If the Secondactivity extends Activity instead of DroidGap, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you must open index.html file implace of second.html and you manage second activity in index.html file